# ImageSource dependency property on a user control - XAML value set throws

Tags: wpf, type-conversion, dependency-properties, converters, imagesource

I've created a small user control consisting of a button whose content is an Image. I created an "ImageSource" dependency property on the user control in order to bind to it from the Image inside the button.

However in the XAML where I placed an instance of my user control setting the property throws an error at runtime :

```
<ctrl:ImageButton ImageSource="/Resources/Images/Icons/x.png" Command="{Binding Reset}"  DisabledOpacity="0.1"/>
```

and at runtime :

'/Resources/Images/Icons/x.png' string is not a valid value for 'ImageSource' property of type     'ImageSource'. 'ImageSource' type does not have a public TypeConverter class.

I then created a converter :

```
public class StringToBitmapImage : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        return new BitmapImage(new Uri((string) value, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

and then decorated my dependency property with it :

```
    [TypeConverter(typeof(StringToBitmapImage))]
    public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        LambdaHelper.GetMemberName<ImageButton>(ib => ib.ImageSource), typeof (ImageSource), typeof (ImageButton));
    [TypeConverter(typeof(StringToBitmapImage))]
    public ImageButton ImageSource
    {
        get { return (ImageButton)GetValue(ImageSourceProperty); }
        set { SetValue(ImageSourceProperty, value); }
    }
```

but still WPF does not convert my string to an ImageSource (BitmapImage) instance...

What to do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several incorrect things here:

First, your CLR property is returning an `ImageButton` whereas the dependency property is defined as an `ImageSource`.

Second, a type converter is not the same as a binding value converter. Your type converter should derive from `TypeConverter` and be applied on the `ImageSource` class rather than on the property itself.

Third, the framework `ImageSource` type already has a `TypeConverterAttribute` with `ImageSourceConverter` as the type converter so everything should work out of the box without having to write a custom converter. Make sure you're not referencing another custom `ImageSource` class in another namespace.

To finish, use `ImageBrush.ImageSource.AddOwner` rather than redefining a whole new dependency property.

**Edit:** to answer Berryl's comment:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ImageSourceProperty = ImageBrush.ImageSource.AddOwner(typeof(ImageButton);
```

This piece of code will reuse the existing ImageSource property rather than defining a new (remember that each different dependency property gets registered in a global static dictionary), only defining a new owner and optionally a new metadata. It's like `OverrideMetadata` but from an outside class.

Comment: can you show in code how that last part (ImageBrush.ImageSource.AddOwner) would be used? Cheers